# Weak Compactness Theorem for Borel Measures

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets, borel-measures

Weak convergence is defined as follows:

> The sequence $\{\mu_j\}$ of Borel measures on $\Bbb R^n$ converges weakly to a Borel measure $\mu$ if for all $f\in C_0(\Bbb R^n)$, $$\int f d\mu_j \to \int f d\mu$$

After this, they state a certain *weak compactness theorem*, which is supposed to follow from the separability of $C_0(\Bbb R^n)$.

> **Theorem.** Any sequence $\{\mu_j\}$ of Borel measures on $\Bbb R^n$ satisfying $$\sup_j \mu_j(\Bbb R^n) < \infty$$ has a weakly converging subsequence.

I'm trying to prove the above theorem. Suppose $\{\mu_j\}$ is a sequence of Borel measures on $\Bbb R^n$ satisfying $\sup_j \mu_j(\Bbb R^n) < \infty$. We must find a weakly convergent subsequence $\{\mu_{j_k}\}$, i.e., $$\int fd\mu_{j_k} \xrightarrow{k\to\infty} \int f d\mu$$
for some Borel measure $\mu$, and all $f\in C_0(\Bbb R^n)$. I don't have much clue where to begin; could I please get any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

---

Reference: *Fourier Analysis and Hausdorff Dimension* by Pertti Mattila.

Comment: You can read about 'vague convergence' in K L Chung's book.

Comment: This is an application of Alaoglu's theorem and the Riesz representation theorem: $X=\mathcal{C}_0(\mathbb{R})$, then $X^*=\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ the space of complex (or signed finite) measures, and $X$ is separable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are trying to prove is a simpler version of the [Banach-Alaoglu Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem).

In this case, because $C_0(\mathbb R^n)$ is separable and you have a sequence $\{\mu_j\}$, a slightly more direct argument can be made.

Let $\{f_k\}$ be a dense sequence in $C_0(\mathbb R^n)$. The sequence of numbers $$\Big\{\int f_1\,d\mu_j\Big\}$$
is bounded, and so it admits a convergent subsequence by Heine-Borel. That is, there is a subsequence $\{\mu_{1,m}\}$ such that
$$\Big\{\int f_1\,d\mu_{1,m}\Big\}$$ converges. Next we repeat the argument to obtain a subsequence $\{\mu_{2,m}\}$ of $\{\mu_{1,m}\}$ such that
$$\Big\{\int f_2\,d\mu_{2,m}\Big\}$$ converges. Inductively we construct a subsequence $\{\mu_{k,m}\}$ of $\{\mu_{k-1,m}\}$ such that
$$\Big\{\int f_k\,d\mu_{k,m}\Big\}_m$$ converges. Now one can show that
$$
\lim_k\int f_j\, d\mu_{k,k}
$$
exists for all $j$. Next, the density of $\{f_k\}$ implies that
$$
\varphi(f)=\lim_k\int f\,d\mu_{k,k}
$$
exists for all $f$ and it is a positive linear functional. By Riesz-Markov there exists $\mu$ such that
$$
\int f\,d\mu=\lim_k\int f\,d\mu_{k,k}
$$
for all $f\in C_0(\mathbb R^n)$.

Comment: Looks good! I have some questions though. (1). Why does $$\lim_k\int f_j\, d\mu_{k,k}
$$ exist for all $j \in \Bbb N$? (2). Density ensures that we can find a sequence $\{f_k\}$ with $f_k \xrightarrow{k\to\infty} f$. How does this, and (1), imply that $$\varphi(f)=\lim_k\int f\,d\mu_{k,k}$$ exists for all $f$? Perhaps some Lebesgue DCT-type argument is involved here. (3). Why is $\varphi$ a **positive** functional? The rest is good. Thank you!

Comment: $(1)\ $ $\{\mu_{k,k}\}$, for $k\geq j$,  is a subsequence of $\{\mu_{j,m}\}_m$.

Comment: $(2)\ $ With $c=\sup_k\mu_k(\mathbb R^n)$, 
\begin{align}
\Big|\int f\,d\mu_{k,k}-\int f\,d\mu_{k',k'}\Big|
&\leq\int|f-f_j|\,d\mu_{k,k}+\Big|\int f_j\,d\mu_{k,k}-\int f_j\,d\mu_{k',k'}\Big|
+\int |f_j-f|\,d\mu_{k',k'}\\
&\leq 2c\|f-f_j\|_\infty+\Big|\int f_j\,d\mu_{k,k}-\int f_j\,d\mu_{k',k'}\Big|.
\end{align}
Then
$$
\lim_{k,k'\to\infty}\Big|\int f\,d\mu_{k,k}-\int f\,d\mu_{k',k'}\Big|
\leq 2c\|f-f_j\|_\infty.
$$
As this can be done for any $j$, the limit is zero and so $\lim_k\int f\,d\mu_{k,k}$ exists.

Comment: $(3)\ $ Because if you evaluate on a non-negative function, you get a non-negative number. That's exactly the condition you need to get a measure in Riesz-Markov.

Comment: $(1)$ is still not clear. Take $j = 1$ for example. Then, $\{\mu_{k,k}\}$ is not a subsequence of $\{\mu_{1,m}\}_{m}$ for $k\ge 1$. Certainly $\mu_{1,1}$ is in $\{\mu_{1,m}\}_{m}$, but $\mu_{2,2}, \mu_{3,3}, \ldots$ are clearly not in the sequence $\{\mu_{1,m}\}_{m}$ (the first index is always $1$).

Comment: "Clearly",  how? From the answer:  *Inductively we construct a subsequence* $\{μ_{k,m}\}$ of $\{μ_{k−1,m} \}\ldots$